# BanzaiCloud Operator Output log from different namespace to S3

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, logging, banzaicloud-logging-operator

I have a specific namespace that I am trying to output logs into Amazon S3 using Banzai cloud Logging operator.I Am currently using ClusterFlow and ClusterOutput but it is not working for me and not able to see the logs in S3 bucket.

Here are the images of the code that I have:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Nnz.jpg

I have tried reaching out to the Banzai Cloud Slack to no avail. Can someone help me check the yaml files and validate them?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Flow object and not ClusterFlow.

The Flow is a namespaced resource, which means logs will only be collected from the namespace that the Flow is deployed in. Where as ClusterFlow is scoped at the cluster level and can configure log collection across all namespaces.